# Problem loading images (JPG, PNG…) after uploading system to approval / production environment

Tags: node.js, reactjs, multer

I am facing a problem with broken images (png, jpg ..) in an application that we started homologating this week. The application is hosted in an environment that simulates production, with URLs using HTTPS (ex: https://backend.domain.com and https://frontend.domain.com).

What happens is the following, sometimes the images are loaded normally and at other times they do not. This is happening in all images where I get the URL of the backend. Still, images are loading normally. And sometimes they carry it and sometimes they don't. In a development environment, running the services locally, everything works normally.

I will explain a little about my structure:

I have a Postgres database, a backend server (NodeJS with sequelize as ORM) and a frontend (ReactJS). All hosted on Amazon AWS - EC2 for the backend and BucketS3 for the frontend.

The images are saved in a directory on the backend server and record part of their path in the database, as follows:

**File table used to store image information:**
[image]

**Multer configuration:**

```
import multer from 'multer';
import crypto from 'crypto';
import { extname, resolve } from 'path';

const avatar = {
  storage: multer.diskStorage({
    destination: resolve(__dirname, '..', '..', 'tmp', 'uploads'),
    filename: (req, file, cb) => {
      crypto.randomBytes(16, (err, res) => {
        if (err) return cb(err);

        return cb(null, res.toString('hex') + extname(file.originalname));
      });
    },
  }),
};

export default avatar;
```

**And here the model responsible for creating the image URL:**

```
import Sequelize, { Model } from 'sequelize';

class File extends Model {
  static init(sequelize) {
    super.init(
      {
        name: Sequelize.STRING,
        path: Sequelize.STRING,
        url: {
          type: Sequelize.VIRTUAL,
          get() {
            return `${process.env.APP_URL}/files/${this.path}`;
          },
        },
      },
      {
        sequelize,
      }
    );
    return this;
  }
}

export default File;
```

**And now in React, the way I'm using to show the image on the screen is as follows:**

```
<Teacher>
    <img src={module.teacher.avatar.url} alt="avatar" />

    <div>
    <span>Professor:</span>
    <span className="teacher-name">
        {module.teacher.name}
    </span>
    </div>
</Teacher>
```

Here are two prints demonstrating what I mentioned above, notice that the URL of the image is the same for both cases, two different updates of the page are beaten prints:

**Breaking image**
[image]
[image]

**Image ok**
[image]

For what reason does this happen?

Comment: Error 401 says not authorized.

Comment: Yes, but sometimes it does. Changing routes and returning, it is enough to load.